# Python pydantic V2 model_dump_json for subclass leaves out Field

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

I am trying to serialize a pydantic model to JSON with the model_dump_json() function. This works most of the time, but it fails in one particular case where it ignores a mandatory Field of a subclass.

The following stripped-down code fragment illustrates the problem:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List

class T(BaseModel):
    basename:str

    def asJSON(self):
        return self.model_dump_json(indent=4)

class TT(T):
    root:bool

class Map(BaseModel):    
    items:List[T]

    def __init__(self, **data) -> None:
        data['items'] = []        
        super().__init__(**data)

    def asJSON(self):
        return self.model_dump_json(indent=4) 
    
class TMap(Map):
    mapname:str

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = TT(basename="hello", root=False)
    print(f"{type(t1)}")
    print(t1.asJSON())
    m1 = TMap(mapname="MAIN")
    m1.items.append(t1)
    print(f"{type(m1.items[0])}")
    print(m1.items[0].asJSON())
    print(type(m1))
    print(m1.asJSON())
```

When I run this on my computer, it get the following output:

```
<class '__main__.TT'>
{
    "basename": "hello",
    "root": false
}
<class '__main__.TT'>
{
    "basename": "hello",
    "root": false
}
<class '__main__.TMap'>
{
    "items": [
        {
            "basename": "hello"
        }
    ],
    "mapname": "MAIN"
}
```

Why is the instance within List not serialised properly? It misses the Field 'root', even though it *is* a TT instance with that particular Field assigned. When I directly use model_dump_json() on the TT instance it does give me the right output, so why doesn't this work when the TT instance is embedded inside a List in another object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pydantic v2 strictly follows types defined in annotations.

You have defined `Map.items` as `items: list[T]`. This forces Pydantic to always use `T` class' schema for serialization of items here.

To instruct Pydantic to try using a serializer associated with the type of the value in this list you can use [`SerializeAsAny` type](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/serialization/#serializing-with-duck-typing). This forces Pydantic to use duck typing instead of a serializer generated according to a model schema.

Here is your example using `SerializeAsAny`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from pydantic import BaseModel, SerializeAsAny


class T(BaseModel):
    basename: str

    def asJSON(self):
        return self.model_dump_json(indent=4)


class TT(T):
    root: bool


class Map(BaseModel):
    items: list[SerializeAsAny[T]] = []  # Pydantic is smart enough to create a new list for every instance.

    def asJSON(self):
        return self.model_dump_json(indent=4)


class TMap(Map):
    mapname: str


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = TT(basename='hello', root=False)
    print(f'{type(t1)}')
    print(t1.asJSON())
    m1 = TMap(mapname='MAIN')
    m1.items.append(t1)
    print(f'{type(m1.items[0])}')
    print(m1.items[0].asJSON())
    print(type(m1))
    print(m1.asJSON())
```

The output includes `root` field as expected:

```json
<class '__main__.TT'>
{
    "basename": "hello",
    "root": false
}
<class '__main__.TT'>
{
    "basename": "hello",
    "root": false
}
<class '__main__.TMap'>
{
    "items": [
        {
            "basename": "hello",
            "root": false
        }
    ],
    "mapname": "MAIN"
}
```

Be aware though that `SerializeAsAny` could introduce a performance degradation comparing to using a strict serializer.

Comment: This does the trick, thanks. Big fan of Pydantic but not sure if I like the design of this though. IMHO, it goes against common OO sense.

Comment: This is a trade-off that pays for improved performance in this case. We know a serializer, we use it -- no need to determine the one from the values.

Comment: It's also a security issue, if subtypes could have sensitive data in them